# iOS/Objective-C: Adding NSString object to NSMutableArray, NSMutableArray is (null)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
if (urlIndex == maxIndex) { 
    maxIndex = maxIndex + 1;

    NSString* sURL = webpage.request.URL.absoluteString;

    [urlHistory addObject:sURL];
    NSLog(@"%d: %@", urlIndex, [urlHistory objectAtIndex:urlIndex]);
    NSLog(@"%d: %@", urlIndex, webpage.request.URL.absoluteString);


    [sURL release];

    urlIndex = urlIndex + 1;
}
else {
    [urlHistory insertObject:webView.request.URL.absoluteString atIndex:(urlIndex - 1)];
}
}
```

This line

```
    NSLog(@"%d: %@", urlIndex, [urlHistory objectAtIndex:urlIndex]);
```

prints (null), while as this line

```
    NSLog(@"%d: %@", urlIndex, webpage.request.URL.absoluteString);
```

prints the actual URL.

On my initWithNibName I have:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:@"Tab1ViewController" bundle:nil];

if (self) {
    urlHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    urlIndex = 0;
    maxIndex = 0;
}

return self;
}
```

But I still keep getting (null) when I access my array. Why is that?

Comment: Is that a typo in your question, you are adding objects to urlIndex (presumably an integer) and not urlHistory?

Comment: Yeah fixed that thanks, but that was on an irrelevant line tho...

Comment: There are no irrelevant lines :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your `urlHistory` object is `nil`. Calling `-objectAtIndex:` on a `nil` object will return `nil`. You probably forgot to initialize `urlHistory` in your `-init`, or you're not actually calling the `-init` method you think you are (e.g. if your VC is loaded from a nib it will be using `-initWithCoder:` instead of `-initWithNibName:bundle:`).

For the record, if `-objectAtIndex:` on an `NSArray` ever returns `nil`, it means the array itself is `nil`. Since `NSArray` cannot store `nil`, `-objectAtIndex:` with a valid index will never return `nil`, and `-objectAtIndex:` with an invalid index will throw an exception. So the only way for `-objectAtIndex:` to return nil is if the method itself is never actually called.

Comment: On my initWithNibName I already have urlHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; what else can I do?

Comment: @Gibson: I can't really answer that without access to all of your code, but you can verify that this is what's going on by simply logging out `NSLog(@"urlHistory: %@", urlHistory)`. You should see `urlHistory: (null)` logged out.

Comment: @gibson, are you definitely creating the controller using initWithNibName? Have you logged in that method?

Comment: @jrturton you were right, my initWithNibName was being bypassed for some reason. If you resubmit your answer I will accept yours.

Comment: @Gibson: If your view controller is being created inside a nib (e.g. the VC itself is in a nib) then it uses `-initWithCoder:` instead of `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: @jrturton: Yeah, I saw his comment saying that too, which is why I didn't suggest that he had the wrong init method.

Comment: @KevinBallard - just update your answer, it's way better than mine and an extra one would just be noise.